# How do I make the Android emulator full screen on macOS?

Tags: macos, window-manager, fullscreen, android

I set up a custom Android emulator virtual device in Android Studio and everything seems to work perfectly, but I am not able to full screen the emulator window. I can resize the window just fine, but there's no option for full screen.

I tried running the emulator from the command line and passing the flags `-qemu -full-screen`, but it shows:

```
unknown option: -full-screen
please use -help for a list of valid options
```

even though it is included in the `emulator -qemu -help`:

```
-full-screen    start in full screen
```

It looks like this:[image]

Is there any way to make the Android Emulator full screen on macOS?